# Responsive webpage using media queries

Tags: html, css

Hi I have created one login page using HTML and CSS but that is not fit to various devices ie;not responsive.How can I make it responsive using media Queries.Plese suggest any solution.

```
 <html >
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Log-in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="login-card">
            <h1>Login</h1><br>
  <form>
      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number">
      <input type="submit" name="register" class="login login-register" value="Register">    
 </form>

      </div>
      </div> 

 </body>
</html>
```

And This is my CSS

```
 body {
       background: url() no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }

.login-card {
     padding: 2px;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #DCDCDC;
     margin: 0 auto 10px;
     border-radius: 1px 3px 2px;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     overflow: hidden;
            }

.login-card h1 {
     font-weight: 100;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 2.3em;
     }

.login-card input[type=submit] {
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     position: relative;
      }

 .login-card input[type=text], input[type=name] {
     height: 44px;
     font-size: 16px;
     width: 100%;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
     border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    /* border-radius: 2px; */
     padding: 0 8px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius:15px;
     }

  .login-card input[type=text]:hover, input[type=name]:hover {
     border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
     border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     }

   .login {
     text-align:center;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 700;
     height: 36px;
     padding: 0 8px;
     /* border-radius: 3px; */
     /* -webkit-user-select: none;
     user-select: none; */
     }

    .login-register {
     /* border: 1px solid #3079ed; */
     border: 0px;
     border-radius:20px;
     color: #fff;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
     background-color: #4d90fe;
    /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,                  from(#4d90fe), to(#4787ed)); */
      }

 .login-register:hover {
     /* border: 1px solid #2f5bb7; */
     border: 0px;
     text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
     background-color: #357ae8;
     /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,    from(#4d90fe), to(#357ae8)); */
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `meta` tag for mobile browsers

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read up on [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and decide for yourself the best way to implement them into your CSS according to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the Bootstrap framework.

```
http://getbootstrap.com/
```

Thousands of site use Bootstrap to create responsive designs for all platforms.
Getting started is easy and fast.

If you're set on using media queries, you can read up on them here.

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries
```